# Как пройти авторизацию на GitHub из Git Bash через браузер.?

Tags: github

Не могу пройти авторизацию на GitHub через браузер. После ввода в Git Bash команды:  `git push -u origin master` появляется окно от GitHub с предложением войти через браузер - кнопка "Sign in with your browser". После нажатия на кнопку происходит перенаправление в IE. При этом кнопка авторизации не активна. Пожалуйста, объясните как же все-таки пройти авторизацию.

Comment: Как-то связано с прекращением поддержки Credential Manager: https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/master/docs/github-apideprecation.md ?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но я обновил Git до версии 2.29.Не работает именно с этой версией

Comment: А если попробовать другой браузер, вместо IE, поставить по умолчанию?

Comment: По умолчанию у меня стоит Яндекс, но перенаправление почему-то происходит в IE?

Comment: Сменил браузер по умолчанию на Chrome. Все заработало. Спасибо за подсказку.